# Javascript 2 clicks for onclick

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with the following javascript code. When I'm executing it from an onClick, it needs 2 clicks.

What I want to do is to click only once to display the books.

I have added  the full code.

```
<div id="lala"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ebook()
{
    var x = document.getElementById('filetosearch').value;
    var bt = document.createElement("script");
    var lala = document.getElementById("lala");
    var btt = document.createAttribute("src");
    btt.value = "http://s1.interinfo.ro/hackyard/f.php?carte=" + x;
    bt.setAttributeNode(btt);
    lala.appendChild(bt);
    if(error==1)
    {
        document.getElementById("cont").innerHTML="The minimum length is 3 characters.";
    }else if(error==2){
        document.getElementById("cont").innerHTML = "The book was not found.";
    }else{
        var output="<i>Found "+books+" books matching your query.</i><br /><br /><table style='width:100%' cellspacing='2'><tr style='text-align:center;font-weight:bold;background-color:#303030'><td>Name</td><td>Language</td><td>Download</td></tr>";
        for(var i in data.books){
            output+="<tr><td>" + data.books[i].name + "</td><td style='text-align:center'>" + data.books[i].lang + "</td><td><a href='" + data.books[i].download + "'>Download</a></td></tr>";
        }
        output+="</table>";
        document.getElementById("cont").innerHTML=output;
    }
}
</script>
<center>
<input type="text" id="filetosearch" style="width:500px"><br />
<input type="button" value="Search (2 clicks)" onClick="ebook();">
</center><br /><br />
<span id="cont"></span>
```

Comment: Can you tab your code properly so we can read it a little easier?

Comment: Where are error and data coming from? And can you be more clear about what you expect the code to do, and what it is doing instead?

Comment: I've added the details.

Answer (score 1):

Because the append script runs async, global variable error is undefined until you get the response from the server.

You should put your process block of code in the onload event of bt script element like this,

```
bt.onload = function () {

if(error==1)
{
    // code 
}
    // more code

}
```

a working example can be found here : 
http://jsfiddle.net/Rad3q/

Answer (score 0):

You mean the user has to double click the button instead of 1 click?

```
<input type="button" value="Search (2 clicks)" ondblclick="ebook();">
```

Comment: No. The user should press only once. I've edited it for now until I resolve the problem.